# Get the dates in a week using week number using moment.js

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

How to get the dates in a array of a specified week ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "total dates in a week using week number"? Aren't there always 7 days in a week?

Comment: I know there is 7 days. but I want the dates in a particular week. Suppose if i consider current week the i want [22,23,24,25,26,27,28] like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the days of the week 16 of 2015 (ISO):

```js
let days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  .map(d => moment('2015-16-' + d, 'YYYY-W-E'));
console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Use `YYYY-w-e` for locale-sensitive week handling.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan I customized your code according to my requirement but it helps me alot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

**To get the days of the week using weekNumber**, set the week number, get the `startOf` week and iterate to get each date. If no week is specified, 1st week of the year is used.

```js
var dateformat = "YYYY/MM/DD";
function getWeekDaysByWeekNumber(weeknumber)
{
    var date = moment().isoWeek(weeknumber||1).startOf("week"), weeklength=7, result=[];
    while(weeklength--)
    {
        result.push(date.format(dateformat));
        date.add(1,"day")
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getWeekDaysByWeekNumber())
console.log(getWeekDaysByWeekNumber(2))
console.log(getWeekDaysByWeekNumber(25))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**To get the days of the week using date**, set the `startOf` week and iterate to get each date. If no date is specified, `today`'s date is used.

```js
var dateformat = "YYYY/MM/DD";
function getWeekDaysByDate(date)
{
    var date = date ? moment(date,dateformat) : moment(), weeklength=7, result=[];
    date = date.startOf("week")
    while(weeklength--)
    {
        result.push(date.format(dateformat));
        date.add(1,"day")
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getWeekDaysByDate())
console.log(getWeekDaysByDate("2018/07/18"))
console.log(getWeekDaysByDate("2018/06"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```